# Android Emulator - Extended Controls font size

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Is there a way to increase the font size of Android Emulator tooltips and Extended Controls? Searching for an answer online is difficult because mostly people look for ways to manipulate font size in the emulated Android system itself. But my old eyes have a problem seeing the fonts in the emulator menus. See the screenshot:

[image: small fonts in extended properties]

I'm using Android Studio 2021.2.1 on Linux. Thanks in advance for any help.